# Different access for a property from different layers

Tags: .net, domain-driven-design

Say you have an Status property in your domain entity.  This property is used to know the system status of the object, and must be used in a read only way in the presentation layer.  This layer can't modify directly the status property.  Instead, one application service have specific operations that change the status.

Is there a way to make the status property readonly for the presentation layer but writeable by the application service?  Or I'm just modeling this in a wrong way?  I'm using .NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A best practice is to decouple your presentation model from the domain model. Specifically, create a view model and bind the UI to that instead of the domain object directly. The view model can be initialized by passing the domain object into the constructor. Example:

```
class SomeEntity
{
 public string Status { get; set; }
}

class SomeEntityViewModel
{
 public SomeEntityViewModel(SomeEntity e)
 {
  this.Status = e.Status;
 }
 public string Status { get; private set; }
}
```

In this way, an application service can change the status but the view cannot do so directly.